# What is the purpose of these LoginRequiredMixin's attributes in Django 2.0?

Tags: python, django, mixins, python-decorators

I am trying to understand how to implement LoginRequiredMixin in my CBV (Class Based View), but I don't understand the purpose of these attributes;

LoginRequiredMixin attributes:

login_url = settings.LOGIN_URL

redirect_field_name = REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME

raise_exception = False

Note: There is a website that I looked for;

https://django-braces.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/access.html#loginrequiredmixin

Answer (score 3):

The real documentation you're looking for is: [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin)

I will summarize for the sake of having a good answer of StackOverflow.

`login_url` is the url you are going to redirect the unauthorized user to so that they can log in.

`redirect_field_name`, according to [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator), gives an alternate field to reference on login other than the default user.

`raise_exception` tells Django whether to return an HTTP 403 error.

Comment: You said that "redirect_field_name" is an alternate way to specifies the path to redirect to for a successful authenticated user? @rchurch4